# How S3 storage cost works on daily basis?

Tags: amazon-s3

I’ having hard time to calculate S3 storage cost. The case is that I need to store daily backups to it.

The scenario: Let's say that I lease S3 service on 1st of January and send to it 10 files (zip) 10GB each. Then, every single day the 2 oldest files will be deleted and replaced by 2 new ones (10 GB each). So, every day will always stored 100GB of files.

How do I calculate the storage cost in this case? What will i pay at the end of January?

Comment: There is a tool that help to calculate your cost right here http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--cost-calculator.html

Comment: @Tolsadus I used it but it didn't help me.

Comment: The storage cost for s3 storage is 3 cents per GB up to my knowledge. Apart from that network cost will be added based on the upload and download request based on the plan

Answer (score 2):

You're storing 100 GBs. Each day you upload 20 GB (two files, 10GB each), ie. your monthly uploads total 620 GB (20 GB x 31 days).

Request count is quite low (two DELETE requests daily + some requests for uploading etc.) ... Requests are cheap, so let's estimate that you make 2x 100k.

You probably should use standard storage. Then, enter these values to the calculator linked above (https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html).

With estimated values above: If you are just uploading, costs are ~4 dollars per month. If you download something, that increases costs. (100GB downloads => ~$11/month). Your mileage may vary.

[Screenshot of AWS S3 price calculator with example values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqcS5.png)